# Как заменить часть слова?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой текст: **Иван Иванов**
Необходимо используя `preg_repalce`, сделать текст такого вида: **Иван И.**

Пробовал такое регулярное выражение:

```
/\s.(.+)/
```

Подскажите, как правильно его использовать?

Comment: Приведите больше разнообразных примеров текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша регулярное выражение [`\s.(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/wH8xA6/1) ищет в строке пробел, потом всё кроме перевода строки, а потом захватывает всё кроме перевода строки до самого конца.
Т.е. делает вообще не то, что надо. По идее, надо захватить первую букву в группу №1, а остальное просто "вчитать" до конца, чтобы потом отбросить. [Вот так](https://regex101.com/r/wH8xA6/2):

```
$re = "#(?<=\s)(\p{L})\p{L}+#"; 
$str = "Иван Иванов"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "$1.", $str);
```

**Но** лучше всё сделать без "регулярок":

```
$str = "Иван Иванов";
$result = explode(" ", $str);
echo $result[0] . ' ' . mb_substr($result[1], 0, 1) . '.';
```

Результат работы [демо-программы](https://ideone.com/jrxir6):

```
Иван И.
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю в данном случае вместо `preg_replace`, лучше найти позицию пробела, увеличить позицию на один и добавить точку вместо оставшейся строки.

Позицию находит функция `strpos()`, а вырезает подстроку функция `substr()`.

А дальше надо всего лишь немного арифметики.

**Обновление**

```
<?php
    $imiaFamilija = "Ivan Ivanov";
    $pozicija = strpos($imiaFamilija," ");
    $pozicija += 2; 
    echo substr_replace($imiaFamilija, ".",$pozicija);
?>
```

Comment: Можете привести пример?

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравятся предыдущие ответы, но я всё-таки добавлю свою "расширенную" версию. На тот случай, если топик-стартер добавит элемент неопределенности, типа "фамилия иногда отсутствует и бывают ещё вторые имена или отчества".

Надо обрезать *последнее*, а не второе слово и только тогда, когда оно не единственное.

```
<?php
// encoding: utf-8
$array = [
  'Иван Иванов',
  'Петр',
  'Сидор Карпович Распопов',
  'Ахмед-Баба Кармаль'
]; 

foreach ($array as $name) {
    echo preg_replace('/^((?:[^\\s]+\\s)+)([^\\s])(?:.*)$/u', '$1$2.', $name) . "\n";
}
```

Результат:

- Иван И.
- Петр
- Сидор Карпович Р.
- Ахмед-Баба К.